# iOS 6 autolayout positioning problems

Tags: ios6, autolayout

I've been searching, and cannot find an answer that will work for the life of me. I have view in which I want a UILabel to show near the bottom of the view. I've pinned 'bottom space to superview' in IB, and it works fine on the retina 4 simulator, but is positioned off screen on the 3.5 inch. If I try the same steps for the 3.5 inch, it appears too high off the bottom on the 4 inch display. This really shouldn't be this difficult, there's obviously something I'm missing.

Comment: Can you take a picture of your [Document Outline](http://i.imgur.com/tW9RY.png) so we can see all the NSLayoutContraints acting on your View Controller?

Comment: http://i3.photobucket.com/albums/y97/cable_pair/ScreenShot2012-12-21at71108PM_zps16e7868e.png

Comment: Can you widen the Document Outline so I can see the full descriptions of each constraint? Also which label is in question: "Label - ⇆ Swipe to navigate" or "Label - Label"?

Comment: http://i3.photobucket.com/albums/y97/cable_pair/ScreenShot2012-12-21at105857PM_zps91d20bdd.png It's the swipe to navigate label.

Comment: Thanks. The last 2 constraints appear to both define the distance between Label's bottom and View's bottom. I'd suggest deleting either one, or deleting both and re-pinning "bottom space to superview". FYI, every time you use the Pin or Align menu options, XCode creates a new constraint, even if existing an existing constraint already defines the chosen attribute.

Comment: I've tried that, but it still puts the label off screen on the 3.5 inch simulator.

Comment: Can you upload the project?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't upload the project.

Comment: I tried to recreate the problem myself, but couldn't. Let me know if you're able to recreate the problem in a new project that you're comfortable uploading.

Answer (score 0):

your `UILabel` must be corresponding `Vertical Spacing` with another control. Make sue you are not getting any warning in `console` while you are rotating the device/simulator.